# What is the best practice for designing (properly tagging) elements of an XML file that contains paragraphs of data?

Tags: xml

I am creating a template XML file that will be used cross-platform for displaying static data that will not be updated frequently.  Specifically, these XML files will contain formatted "Standard Operating Guidelines" that will be accessed via either a browser and formatted with style sheets (initially) or (later) a native application.

I've searched everywhere I can think of and I am either not searching correctly or I am misunderstanding what I am finding.  Here is an example of the XML I have created so far, with sample data:

```
<fire_sog>
  <organization orgmain="Division">Public Safety Division</organization>
  <organization orgsub="Department">Fire Department</organization>
  <date name="Creation">2009-07-04</date>
  <date name="LRD">2009-07-04</date>
  <section_number>1</section_number>
  <sog_number>0</sog_number>
  <category>Administrative Procedures</category>
  <title>Departmental Chain of Command</title>
</fire_sog>
```

Following the title will be paragraphs of data.

So, as it relates to my question, is there a best practice to embedding/formatting blocks of text into an XML file when each file will have a different amount of text?

If I have not included enough information, please let me know and I will provide more.

Comment: I've used [this XML](http://www.docbook.org/) to implement a set of paragraphs. But it was a text document.

Comment: XML elements can contain any amount of text. If you want to transport *formatted* text and don't want more sub-elements or can't guarantee the well-formedness of that part, use markdown. If you can guarantee the well-formedness, include XHTML right into one of your own elements.

Comment: The guidelines I have been given, that are being imposed by the organization's IT department, are to create the XML without formatting.  The site and applications will use style sheets for format the output based upon the platform accessing the files.  Indices will be created dynamically based upon accessing the data shown in the code snippet above, which will be in each XML file.  Now, since elements can have any amount of text, is the best method going to be to create a single element for all the text and then use control codes / characters to delineate paragraphs of text?

Comment: XML has no "formatting". It is a transport container for structured data, and that's the end of it. What your *application* does with that structured data is up to your application. So I'm not sure I understand what your objection is.

Comment: Only that I would have written a custom application using WPF to manage the data, rather than requiring manual editing of the XML files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xml you provided so far is adequate. If you want to include a bunch of text, just add in another element.

```
<fire_sog>
  ...
  <data>Paragraphs</data>
</fire_sog>
```

The good thing about XML is that you're fairly free to do what you want as long as it conforms to a uniform schema (that you define).

If you're wondering about how many characters should be displayed in terms of width, I typically follow the output maintained by [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/tidy_man.html).

Comment: A schema is not at all necessary with XML. "Width" is completely irrelevant, as well.

Comment: I will definitely be using a schema to format the XML for display.  My next problem, though, is figuring out how dynamically create a "home page" in HTML that will create a list of all the SOGs that can be clicked on and will then take the user to whichever SOG they select.  /sigh This would be a lot easier if I weren't being constrained by the IT department's requirements...

Comment: @Tomalak I agree, but he's asking about best practice, not requirements.

Comment: @jeremy To me it sounds like he's talking about requirements. Even though it's a complete mystery to me *what* requirements he is talking about, exactly.

Comment: @eMedic A schema is not used to format XML for display. It is used for structural validation. One way to format XML for display (for example turn it into HTML) would be XSLT. There are many others, it all depends on your skill set and requirements. You are being extremely vague about what restrictions you are facing anyway, so maybe you could expand on that a little more.

Comment: @Tomalak That's true. I was going off the "best practice" comment, but it does seem like mixing what's possible, what's required for the application, and what's best.